# adding colour in a django models.TextField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model in django:

```
introduction = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
```

When writing in the text field I want the colour of the middle section to be different from the rest. Any ideas how I do this how to set colours in the textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your textfield an identifier in your html code ,

like, id="tf"

then css will be

```
#tf{
 color : #aaaaaa;
}
```

write your color code in place of #aaaaaa.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get what you mean by 'middle section', but regardless, this would have to be done in client-side since what you want is to manipulate something like the color of a certain TextField. You could do it by using the CSS color properties or even Javascript.